# Jetty 8.1 cannor resolved The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jetty, jstl, war

I have a problem. When I trie to run my war with Jetty it give the problem I mentioned. I all places I searched for a solution they said that maybe de standard.jar or the jstl.jar  are not found, but they are at WEBINF/lib. A rare thing is that, it proyect, when I run it from eclipse it go fine. What could be the problem? I have Ecplise Indigo Release 2 , Jetty 8.1 , its a Maven project. Thanks.-

Comment: Could you be using the wrong URI to reference the tag library? What does content assist offer you for the URI value in the taglib directive?

Comment: It solutioned. A partner change the version of Jetty and its run, Thanks